# How do I do "starts with" regex filter in phpunit

Tags: regex, phpunit

I tried this
`phpunit --debug  --filter /^complete/ feed.php;`

For some reason it says 0 tests.

If I do `phpunit --debug  --filter /complete/ feed.php;` it hits any function with the word "complete"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the fully qualified `$name` of the test is represented as `Classname::testname`

So you need to use `::` instead of `^`

Like:

```
$ phpunit --filter /::testIs/
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/.../phpunit.xml

..

Time: 1 second, Memory: 10.75Mb

OK (2 tests, 4 assertions)
```

Comment: Thanks, had no idea. "The pattern can be either the name of a single test or a regular expression that matches multiple test names." isn't very clear in the manual

Comment: @Dave Stein: Indeed it is not. I just found the place it is being filtered and looked over `$filter` and `$name` --- https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php#L718